# how to style html elements which are in different levels of recursive html?

Tags: css, reactjs

I try to create such tree:
[image]
I have such markup

```
<div className='branch'>
          <div className='child'>leaf1</div>
            <div className='parent'>
              <div className='branch'>
                <div className='child'>leaf2</div>
                <div className='parent'>
                  <div className='branch'>
                    <div className='child'>leaf3</div>
                    <div className='parent'></div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='branch'></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I need to add pseudo element in the form of branch(stick to cards from top to f and m) to branch that has leaf2 in my code, but that pseudo element is adding to every branch on every level.
I tried a lot of options that i would not attach here.If someone knows how to do this, show example please!

By the way, I use React and that html code is inside of component Tree, what i mean is that should not be used tree class.

Comment: You can use the child combinator to target elements only if they a child of a certain other element, `.branch > .parent > .branch > .child { ... }`

Comment: i tried :.branch  .parent .branch::after{...} and .branch > .parent  .branch::after{...} It is added style to last two branches.

Comment: You need to use the child combinator `>` on _all_ the levels. `.parent .branch` selects _any_ `.branch` elements inside `.parent`, no matter how "deep" in there they might be. You need `.parent > .branch` to only select `.branch` elements that are a _child_ of `.parent`.

Comment: I understand, tried that .branch > .parent > .branch::after . It is added to expected branch, but also it is added to deeper branches.

Comment: Yes, because `.branch > .parent > .branch` also matches on "leaf3" in your example - that is a `.branch` that is a child of a `.parent` that is a child of a `.branch`. You need to add something, so that the first `.branch` in the selector targets only the top-level `.branch` element. (Like f.e., give it an ID, and select it via that.)